# Angular2 not working on Safari 9.1.2

Tags: angular, typescript, safari, cross-browser

I have a problem running angular2 app on **Safari 9.1.2**. All other higher versions are working. Here is my nothing saying error:
[image]

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Client app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "xxxxxxx"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.2",
    "npm": "3.10.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev_build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config ./config/webpack-dev.config.js",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config ./config/webpack-prod.config.js",
    "postbuild": "rollup --config ./config/rollup.config.js",
    "build_dev": "npm run dev_build && npm start",
    "build_prod": "npm run build && npm run postbuild",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "*",
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "^0.16.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "4.0.0",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.32",
    "@types/geojson": "1.0.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.30.0",
    "@types/pusher-js": "*",
    "@types/turf": "^3.5.32",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "^3.0.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "d3-array": "*",
    "d3-brush": "*",
    "d3-collection": "*",
    "d3-color": "*",
    "d3-dispatch": "*",
    "d3-drag": "*",
    "d3-ease": "*",
    "d3-force": "*",
    "d3-format": "*",
    "d3-hierarchy": "*",
    "d3-interpolate": "*",
    "d3-path": "*",
    "d3-quadtree": "*",
    "d3-scale": "*",
    "d3-selection": "*",
    "d3-shape": "*",
    "d3-time": "*",
    "d3-time-format": "*",
    "d3-timer": "*",
    "d3-transition": "*",
    "express": "4.13.x",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",    
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "luxbar": "^0.3.2",
    "mapbox-gl": "0.32.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-data-table": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-page-slider": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^0.6.0-1",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "ng2-toasty": "2.5.0",
    "primeng": "^2.0.6",
    "primeui": "^3.0.2",
    "pusher-js": "^3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.1",
    "turf": "3.0.14",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "webpack-cleanup-plugin": "^0.5.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vimeo/player": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rollup": "^0.41.6",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-globals": "^1.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "transform-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack-sources": "^0.2.3",
    "webworkify-webpack": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

We have tested our app on all browsers -> Chrome 48,49,50+, Firefox 49,50+, Safari 10+, Opera, Edge etc. All of them are working fine, except Safari 9.1.2. Any advice?

**EDIT**

debugging line by line, here is what console debugger shows:
When opening **_reportError** I see this:
[image]

Opening the **_getDependenciesMetadata** see this:
[image]

opening the **_getTypeMetadata** see this: 
[image]

opening the **_loadDirectiveMetadata** see this:[image]

Comment: Seems to be an issue when resolving DI for some component or service. Can you debug into those lines to see when the error occurs what exactly those OBjects are?

Comment: Also maybe look into required polyfills for safari 9 - for example I know there were some issues with [date pipes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1675), but perhaps you're missing something else.

Comment: it looks like an injection problem - it most probably is a circular dependency - meaning that a service injects another service - while the other service does the same. make sure you do not have such a circular dependency

Comment: I have checked out all services and Injections and we have no circular dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have refactored my code and realised that the problem was really in including circular dependency. I had to keep my code clean and simple and inject DI only where is really needed and use best practices like inheritance and global injection